# Does converting light's linear momentum into angular momentum (SAM or OAM) cause it to redshift?

Tags: optics, angular-momentum, polarization, redshift

Can all of an electromagnetic wave's momentum be changed to orbital angular momentum? I'd imagine this would be easier to test with radio waves.

Comment: The transformation makes no sense at all to begin with.

Comment: Emilio, thanks for the input. I was under the impression that light passing through a spiral phase plate gains orbital angular momentum and therefore loses linear momentum (due to conservation). Am I wrong about this? Where does the angular momentum come from?

Comment: Linear and angular momentum are independently conserved - you cannot turn one into the other. The angular momentum comes from the fact that the process exerts a torque on the spiral phase plate.

Comment: Perhaps I am looking at this too much from a mechanical perspective, but to me it seems similar to a scenario in which a stream of water encounters a stationary (fixed) propeller and begins to twist as it passes. Obviously an unfixed spiral phase plate will rotate when placed under a laser just as an unfixed propeller will spin in a stream of water. I suppose it is wrong to view a spiral phase plate as a momentum conversion device like this?

Comment: In the case you propose the water had angular momentum with respect to the shaft to begin with.

Comment: @james, in the water and propeller analogy, the water stream experiences a torque, but the ship with the fixed propeller experiences an equal and opposite torque.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty perhaps conversion from linear to angular energy is better phrasing? If light gains angular energy it has to come from somewhere. I figured it lost linear energy and gained angular energy. Where does this angular momentum/energy come from?

Comment: @James There's no such thing as "angular energy".

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thank you for your patience. You said that the angular momentum "comes from the fact that the process exerts a torque on the spiral phase plate". Isn't the torque on the phase plate a product of the generation of angular momentum in the light (Newton's 3rd Law)? By "angular energy" I was referring to the energy stored within the light due to its angular momentum. Similar to the kinetic energy stored in a rotating flywheel. I'm trying to understand where this energy comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orbital angular momentum is computed around a particular axis. Usually, that axis is assume to be the general propagation direction of a beam. However, nothing prevent one from taking the axis to be perpendicular to the direction of propagation and displaced away from the beam. In that case, the OAM would be able to use all the momentum to define the OAM. Unfortunately, this is not very useful.

If one conforms to convention and use the general propagation axis to define the OAM in a beam, then only the transverse part of the Poynting vector of the field will contribute to the OAM. For paraxial beams, this part of the Poynting vector is small compare to the logitudinal component.

---

Some clarification, following from the comments. In the earth-moon system some rotational energy is transfered from the earth to the moon via the tidal effect. So there is such a thing as rotational energy. This may be what is refered to as "angular energy" in the comments.

However, a light beam does not undergo a rigid body rotation and therefore does not have rotation energy. It is a common misconception that orbital angular momentum in light implies a rigid body rotation. What a spiral wave plate does is to tilt the light on opposite sides of the beam in slightly different directions so that the beam as a whole becomes twisted, but that does not mean that the beam rotates. Each point in the beam still propagates in a straight line as in geometric optics. The twist introduce small transverse components that contribute to the OAM in the beam.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think I understand it now. It appears that the light has angular momentum as a result of it's "shape" rather than actual rotation. Similar to how a flying screw with a velocity and no spin can transfer angular momentum to whatever it hits as it "digs in".

Answer (score 1):

The word “change” in your question suggests that some transformation might be done to the light beam that decreases the beam’s linear momentum while increasing its angular momentum.  A simple space translation of the beam to $\vec{r}$ will change the angular momentum (OAM) of the beam by $\vec{r} \times \vec{p}$ (wrt the translator’s coordinate system).
$$
<J_k>_{new}=<e^{-r_i P_i} \quad J_k \quad e^{r_j P_j}>=<J_k>_{old}+(\vec{r}\times<\vec{P}>)_k
$$
However, this transformation does not change the linear momentum $\vec{p}$ of the beam since all components of the translation generators $\vec{P}$ commute with each other (ie: translations in free space don’t change linear momentum).
$$
<P_k>_{new}=<e^{-r_i P_i} \quad P_k \quad e^{r_j P_j}>=<P_k>_{old}
$$
 So, at least spatial translation in free space is not a transformation which “changes (converts)” linear momentum to angular momentum.  Since the linear momentum is unchanged, there is no red shifting of the light beam.